# Are questions asking for ideas for designing in Minecraft on-topic?

Tags: discussion, minecraft

Personally I like building in Minecraft a lot, and [What topics can I ask about here?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) is unclear on whether asking for ideas for designing (maybe it falls on the first bullet?), and so far I haven't seen such questions. So are these kind of question on-topic?

Comment: That page is a good starting point - you should also take a look at [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask), which gives some criteria for questions that are off-topic. Asking for ideas would be a poll-type question, which would be off-topic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, they are not.  It's because the questions are totally subjective; there's no way to judge the value of an answer except by what the reader personally likes, making it a popularity contest.  It's basically a vague, unbound list.

The only way this would work is if you had a specific, concrete build in mind, such as a cannon, and you were missing something that would make it work.  "Why doesn't it fire?" That's objective, and answers just have to solve the narrow, focused problem.